# Joomla 4 / 5 Module Layouts naming

Tags: joomla-4.x, language, custom-module, joomla-5.x

When using the following field in my module xml:

```
<field
                    name="layout"
                    type="modulelayout"
                    label="JFIELD_ALT_LAYOUT_LABEL"
                    class="form-select"
                    default="_:default"
                    validate="moduleLayout"
                />
```

It gives me a list of all php files in the tmpl folder to select. I've noticed now that on the Standard Modules these names are listed (inside this selection) as language constants. On my Custom Module it only renders the filename (in lowercase) even if I use the same fieldtype as, for example used in mod_menu (xml above).

mod_menu:
[image: mod_menu field options]

my module:
[image]

What do I need to have there also the language constants and not just the name.
Sidenote: in the mod_menu module the files are also just named "default.php" and collapse-default.php"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind - I've found now the Modulelayout.php file and row 145 explains what happens:

```
...
$text = $lang->hasKey($key = strtoupper($module . '_LAYOUT_' . $value)) ? Text::_($key) : $value;

...
```

So there needs to be a language key setted up in the correct format like `MOD_MODULENAME_LAYOUT_*FILENAME*="Your Name"` in the modules language file.

I've updated the docs...